# Call method with parameters in onclick event

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call method with parameter in java script `onclick='addAlertDlg.show();preparePOIAlertToCreate(name)'`

```
function preparePOIAlertToCreate(name){
    alert(name);
    document.getElementById('bottomForm:refId').value = name;       
}
```

But `alert(name);` showing nothing.

any thing wrong in my code?

Comment: What is `name` and where is it defined?

Comment: have you assigned anything to name variable ?

Comment: Does "showing nothing" mean that an alert pops up but is blank, as might happen if your _name_ variable is set to an empty string, or is not declared at all in which case it'll be the built-in  _window.name_ property that is quite likely an empty string? Or do you mean that nothing happens at all (no alert)?

Comment: yeh i have assigned value to 'name' @ LightStyle, @ SKV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use inline event handling. Use the following approach:

```
var element = document.querySelector(".your-link-class");
element.addEventListener("click", function() {
    addAlertDlg.show();
    preparePOIAlertToCreate(name);
});
function preparePOIAlertToCreate(name){
    alert(name);
    document.getElementById('bottomForm:refId').value = name;       
}
```

If you do this you will find out that *name* is probably not defined. Also you will get a good feedback in the console.

Answer (score 0):

try calling function as

```
onclick='addAlertDlg.show();preparePOIAlertToCreate("name")'
```

if you dont put 'name' in quotation marks, js will search a variable named 'name', so it cant find anything and cant show anything.

Answer (score 0):

The way you use the function is right, but I guess you didn't set the *name* any value.